# Maven Archetypes for Scala web app

Tags: scala, maven, akka, reactive-programming

Is there a maven archetype for building a reactive web app with, Akka, and NoSQL database like mongo DB to deploy in SBT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archetype is not important. The project must have a correct anatomy.

For example:

```
project
|_build.properties      <= specifies what version of sbt to use
|_build.scala           <= dependencies and project config are set in here
|_plugins.sbt           <= sbt plugins can be added here

src
|_ main
|  |_ scala
|  |  |   |_ScalatraBootstrap.scala     <= mount servlets in here
|  |  |_org
|  |      |_ yourdomain
|  |         |_ projectname
|  |            |_ MyScalatraServlet.scala
|  |_ webapp
|     |_ WEB-INF
|        |_ views
|        |  |_ hello-scalate.scaml
|        |_ layouts
|        |  |_ default.scaml
|        |_ web.xml
|_ test
   |_ scala
      |_ org
         |_ yourdomain
            |_ projectname
               |_ MyScalatraServletSpec.scala
```

Comment: This structure is valid to deploy in any server?

Answer (score 0):

No, but IDEs do a good job of generating the project structure.

Comment: wich IDE for example?